# C++/CX - How to create a two dimensional Array<byte> in Window Runtime component

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, c++-cx

I am fairly new to C++/CX programming, please correct the question for any mistakes.

I am trying to create a Public API in Windows Runtime using C++/CX, where I have to define a method which has two dimensional `byte` array as `out` parameter. I think, I cannot use `Array<byte>^` for this purpose as it is suppose to be a one dimensional array. But Visual Studio complier suggests me to have declaration like below

`void getByteArrays(int *size, Array<byte>^* arr);`

1. But I cannot initialize `arr` in the implementation, I think the reason is same, `Array` can be only one dimensional array?

But I can still send `Array<byte>^` though using below initialization.

```
byte *buffer = /* Something */ ;
arr[0] = ref new Array<byte>(buffer, size);
```

2. Is this approach correct?
3. If not, what is the best way to have a two dimensional `byte` array as out parameter using `Platform namespace` only?

Below is my complete code

```
void getByteArrays(int *size, Array<byte>^* arr)
{
    byte *buffer = /* Something */;
    (*size) = /* Something */;

    arr = ref new Array<byte>(2); //How do i tell compiler that it has 2 rows?
    arr[0] = ref new Array<byte>(buffer, (*size));
    arr[1] = ref new Array<byte>(buffer, (*size));
}
```

**Update** : I think, complier was suggesting to pass the `Array<byte>^` pointer as reference for `out` parameter. So, it is still be a one-dimensional array.

Comment: Do check [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/array-and-writeonlyarray-c-cx), it explicitly mentions that this is not supported (Jagged Array section).  You have to expose it as a vector-of-vectors, `IVector<IVector<T>^>`

Comment: It appears to be the case, as the complier was trying to tell me to pass the reference of `Array<byte>^`. Can you provide an example or reference, if you have any?

Comment: If you want use the two dimensional Array, please refer [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new).